# k <= n is not TRUE in rollmeanr

Tags: r, rcpp

I have the following matrix:

```
            X1     X2     X3     X4      X5      X6     X7     X8      X9    X10
A.DCE  3838.00 3838.0 3838.0 3838.0 3838.00 3837.00 3837.0 3836.0 3835.00 3824.0
AG.SHF 3840.00 3841.0 3842.0 3842.0 3842.00 3846.00 3846.0 3848.0 3847.00 3854.0
AU.SHF  272.75  272.8  272.8  272.8  272.85  272.85  272.9  272.9  272.95  273.1
I.DCE   493.00  492.5  493.0  493.0  491.00  491.00  491.0  491.0  491.50  494.5
IC.CFE 5968.60 5971.8 5970.0 5967.6 5972.20 5973.00 5973.6 5973.6 5978.00 6052.2
IF.CFE 3691.40 3693.8 3694.0 3696.0 3700.00 3699.00 3699.4 3698.8 3702.20 3701.2
IH.CFE 2652.20 2653.6 2653.6 2656.8 2664.40 2660.00 2658.0 2661.4 2662.00 2639.4
J.DCE  1897.50 1897.0 1898.0 1897.0 1896.00 1896.00 1895.0 1895.0 1896.00 1883.0
JM.DCE 1223.00 1222.0 1222.5 1222.0 1220.50 1220.50 1218.5 1221.0 1221.50 1205.0
M.DCE  2811.00 2811.0 2811.0 2812.0 2811.00 2812.00 2811.0 2810.0 2810.00 2810.0
RB.SHF 3658.00 3658.0 3661.0 3660.0 3654.00 3656.00 3652.0 3652.0 3653.00 3636.0
Y.DCE  6102.00 6102.0 6106.0 6104.0 6102.00 6098.00 6094.0 6090.0 6094.00 6084.0
ZC.CZC  614.20  614.0  614.2  614.0  613.80  613.80  613.8  614.0  614.00  611.6
```

I want to apply roll-mean to every row. When I call this function from `Rcpp` package

```
rollmeanr((df_close[2,]),2,fill=NA)
```

I receive this error: `Error: k <= n is not TRUE`

Although when I do the same on columns in works well

Answer (score 0):

That function "prefers" columns as is for time series.

This should work:

```
rollmeanr(t(df_close[,-1])[,2],2,fill=NA)
```